# Sending Twilio Sms with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, controller, sms, twilio

Can't seem to get my Twilio rails app to send sms.  Here's the controller configured to handle Twilio Smss:

When I play around with this using localtunnel hosting my Twilio number will receive smss and correctly create Sms class instances.  But when it enters the `else` block, it doesn't actually send a reply sms.  The number is in @sms.from is a simple cell in the '+1xxxxxxxxxx' format.  Any ideas why this doesn't work?  I've checked their API and seem to be following it to the T.

```
class SmsController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end

  def create

    @sms = Sms.create(:from => params['From'], :body=> params['Body'], :to=>params["To"], :uri=>params['Uri'])

    if Answer.exists?(params['Body'].to_i)
      @answer = Answer.find(params['Body'].to_i) 
      binding.pry
      @answer.upvote
    else 
      @message = client.account.sms.messages.create(
      :from => '+13473217539',
      :to => @sms.from,
      :body => "Sorry that wasn't a valid option"
      )
      puts @message
      binding.pry 
    end
    render :nothing => true
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/smtp'
require 'sendsms'

w2s = SendSms.new "username","password"
w2s.send "send number", "sms content"
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem, this gem interferes with the Twilio client.  Do **NOT** use it in development:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sms-spec'
```